# TypeError: cant compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I get `datetime` object from email message and then I try to compare it with `datetime.now()`.

And then I see this error:

```
datetime.now() > datetime.strptime('Fri, 31 Jan 2020 09:59:34 +0000 (UTC)', "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z (%Z)"

TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Are you perhaps using Django? If so, Django offers a library for this kind of a problem: django.utils.timezone. from django.utils import timezone timezone.now()

Answer (score 24):

In many cases, you don't want to have to convert any time zone information. To prevent this, just convert the datetime objects to floats on both sides of the comparator. Use the `datetime.timestamp()` function.

I also suggest you simplify your date parsing with `dateutil.parser.parse().` It's easier to read.

In your example, you might compare your datas like this:

```
compare_date = 'Fri, 31 Jan 2020 09:59:34 +0000 (UTC)'
datetime.now().timestamp() > parse(compare_date).timestamp()
```

Comment: How can I use `.timestamp()` if I have a Pandas dataframe containing datetime objects?

Answer (score 9):

As said in [the `datetime` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html), `date` and `time` objects are categorized as “aware” or “naive” depending on whether or not they include time zone information.

To update your `datetime.datetime.now()` from *naive* to *aware* you can use `datetime.timezone.utc`.

I also recommend you to use `dateutil.parser` to parse your generic date/time string to a `datetime.datetime` object.

Here an example of what you could do:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from dateutil import parser

datetime.now(timezone.utc) > parser.parse('Fri, 31 Jan 2020 09:59:34 +0000 (UTC)')
```

See [the `datetime.timezone` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timezone) and [the `dateutil.parser` documentation](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) for more information.

Comment: If you want to avoid timezone bugs this is the way to go because the now datetime has the correct timezone from the beginning. All the other answers leave room for bugs.

Answer (score 8):

This will happen any time you compare an offset-naive (`datetime.now()` No Timezone info) to an offset-aware (UTC) time. Python has poor timezone support by default. Even if you used `datetime.utcnow()` to compare this technically just returns you the UTC time but still has a naive timezone.

My suggestion is to install the `pytz` package and do:

```py
import pytz

datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC) > \
    datetime.strptime('Fri, 31 Jan 2020 09:59:34 +0000 (UTC)',
                      "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z (%Z)")
```

For further reference see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow

Answer (score 4):

You can do like below

`print(datetime.today().timestamp() < object.datetime.timestamp())`

or

```
object.datetime.timestamp()) > datetime.today().timestamp()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
naive_dt = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
aware_dt = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)
```

You can also (ab)use the `isoformat()` and `fromisoformat()` to add your own offset:

```py
aware_dt = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()+'+20:00')
```