# Filter icalendar events based on a time frame breaks because of datetime comparison

Tags: python, datetime, icalendar

I am trying to pull events from an ics file within the next month but making my own datetime and comparing to the datetime in the ics file doesn't seem to be working and is giving the error `TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes`

I tried the answers found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60003764/typeerror-cant-compare-offset-naive-and-offset-aware-datetimes) but still get the same error. Below is the code I am using.

```
def read_from_cal():
    g = open('calendar.ics', 'rb')
    gcal = Calendar.from_ical(g.read())
    year = datetime.now().year
    month = datetime.now().month
    day = datetime.now().day
    hour = datetime.now().strftime("%H")
    minute = datetime.now().strftime("%M")

    next_month = datetime(int(year), int(month)+1, int(day), int(hour), int(minute), 0, tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
    #next_month = next_month.replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
    for component in gcal.walk():
        if component.name == "VEVENT":
            # time printed out in format:
            #      year-month-day hour:min:sec
            summ = component.get('summary')
            start = component.get('dtstart').dt
            end = component.get('dtend').dt
            if now <= start <= next_month:
                print("Worked")
                print(summ, start, end)
```

I've tried both with using `replace` to change my time to utc and just putting it in the `next_month` variable itself and they both give the same error above.

I've also tried [this](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/python/how+to+fix+can%27t+compare+offset-naive+and+offset-aware+datetimes) and [this](https://www.py4u.net/discuss/20886) to no avail.

Comment: Do you have the same error if set tzinfo=None ?

Comment: @GonzaloOdiard Sadly I do. Edit: it looks like it runs but also doesn't seem to do any of the sorting and throws the error at the end.

Comment: @GonzaloOdiard Actually, the lack of sorting seems to be me messing up that `if` statement. It does sort but after a single event gives the same error. My `if` statement now looks like `if now <= start <= next_month` so it should be grabbing everything between now and next month but it grabs one event then errors out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried with a .ics file generated here, so could not be the same problem, but in some cases start is a `datetime.datetime` and in other cases is a `datetime.date`.

This solution worked with my .ics file

```
from icalendar import Calendar
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta


def read_from_cal():
    g = open('example.ics', 'rb')
    gcal = Calendar.from_ical(g.read())
    today = datetime.now()
    next_month =  today + relativedelta(months=1)
    for component in gcal.walk():
        if component.name == "VEVENT":
            summ = component.get('summary')
            start = component.get('dtstart').dt
            end = component.get('dtend').dt
            if isinstance(start, datetime):
                start = start.replace(tzinfo=None)
                if start <= next_month:
                    print("Worked (datetime)")
                    print(summ, start, end)
            else:
                # some events are stored as a date
                if start <= next_month.date():
                    print("Worked (date)")
                    print(summ, start, end)

read_from_cal()
```

Comment: I literally just started working on this again after spending all day making no progress and just started to think that the issue could have something to do with `start`'s timezone! Thank you so much for the help, I spent hours on this thing!